# How to escape the pipe symbol in jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, templating

In jade the pipe symbol (`|`) is used for plain text output. What if I want to write it in page? How can I escape it?

Comment: Have you tried using `&#124;` directly?

Comment: no, but it's not too handy. I've found a first solution, though, see below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just found a possible solution: use the pipe itself to escape the pipe instruction:

```
|| hello
```

will output

```
| hello
```

and that's true for about any reserved symbol: us the pipe in front so it will be treated as plain text